# javascript arguments anonymous function

Tags: javascript, arguments, anonymous-function, opendatabase

Could someone please explain `function(tx)` in the code snippet below, from this page: http://www.webkit.org/demos/sticky-notes/.
Where and how is `tx` assigned?  I have looked [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#dom-database-transaction) for information but am still in the dark.

What I think I understand is that that the **saveAsNew** method of the object is being defined as an anonymous function that first creates a timestamp and creates a local reference to itself (note=this), and then invokes the **transaction** method of the **db** object, providing to that method a parameter which is yet another anonymous function that has an argument **tx**.  But I don't understand where **tx** is coming from.

```
   .
   .
   .
      saveAsNew: function()
         {
             this.timestamp = new Date().getTime();        
             var note = this;
             db.transaction(function (tx)   
                 {
                 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO WebKitStickyNotes (id, note, timestamp, left, top, zindex) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,                   ?)", [note.id, note.text, note.timestamp, note.left, note.top, note.zIndex]);
                 }); 
    },
    .
    .
    .
```

[**FULL CODE PASTE**](http://pastebin.com/MvDWYfJa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have used any variable, so long as in the your anonymous method definition you use the same variable. The transaction method will pass a value as the first parameter when calling your anonymous method and it will be assigned to tx.

Answer (score 1):

First, `tx` is a parameter definition. You can choose any name, it could also be `bar`. It is not different from defining a function as

```
function foo(bar) {

}
```

If you wonder "who" is passing this argument, then it is probably `db.transaction`. You are passing the function as a [**callback** *<sup>[Wikipedia]</sup>*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29). Somewhere `db.transaction` will call:

```
callback(transaction);
```

Maybe this example helps it to understand:

```
function hello(callback) {
    // do some very important world changing computations... then:
    callback('Hello ');
}

hello(function(foobar) {
    alert(foobar + 'Tim!');
});
// alerts 'Hello Tim!'
```

Here, the `hello` function passes one parameter to the callback function.

Comment: Thanks. I need a new ideogram: Enlightenment+Confusion.

Comment: @Tim: If you are still confused, let me know ;)

Comment: I think the fog is clearing. The program is invoking function A and telling A to invoke function B which is being passed to A as an argument. If B itself requires an argument, the program is "trusting" A to provide it.

Comment: @Tim: Something like this. You could also say that `A` requires `B` to accept one argument. But that depends on what `A` is doing, so it is situation dependent. Overall, you are right. *edit:* the original text of this comment.

Comment: @Tim: What I meant with my comment was, that sometimes, `B` might have to return a value for `A` to work.... sorry if I confused you more...

Answer (score 0):

If I knew what `transaction()` was I might be able to help you more.

But I believe it is something that function returns.

Like click has a `event` that is returned

So somewhere in the `transaction` code a variable is sent to the function which you can then name and use in your code.

---

From earlier on the code:

```
db = openDatabase("NoteTest", "1.0", "HTML5 Database API example", 200000);
```

You have to look into what `openDatabase` does that has the `transaction` function.

[You can read up on `openDatabase()` here](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/)

Answer (score 0):

The function saveAsNew returns a function that takes tx as an argument:

```
var new = saveAsNew();
new(tx);
```

as to where tx comes from, it's impossible to say from this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The db.transaction() function must take an argument that is a function that takes one parameter (function(tx) in your example).

It is probably documented as db.transaction(callback).

The parameter tx is sent to the callback function (anonymous function(tx) in your case) by the db.transaction() function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to this:

```
 saveAsNew: function()
     {
         this.timestamp = new Date().getTime();        
         var note = this;
         function booga(tx)
         {
             tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO WebKitStickyNotes (id, note, timestamp, left, top, zindex) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,                   ?)", [note.id, note.text, note.timestamp, note.left, note.top, note.zIndex]);
         }
         db.transaction(booga);
},
```

Where does the "tx" come from in "booga(tx)"? Answer: Whoever calls booga will pass a parameter, and tx is the name we gave to that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The function call `db.transaction()` itself requires one parameter.  That parameter is itself a function that `db.transaction()` will call and when it calls that function, it will pass it one parameter.  The name `tx` can be anything, it's just a name for the first parameter to this function.

Your code could have been written with that function that you are passing to `db.transaction()` as an anonymous function like you did here:

```
db.transaction(function (tx)   
{
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO WebKitStickyNotes (id, note, timestamp, left, top, zindex) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,                   ?)", [note.id, note.text, note.timestamp, note.left, note.top, note.zIndex]);
});
```

or it could have been written this way where it's a little more obvious what is happening, but not as compact:

```
function writeSql(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO WebKitStickyNotes (id, note, timestamp, left, top, zindex) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,                   ?)", [note.id, note.text, note.timestamp, note.left, note.top, note.zIndex]);
}

db.transaction(writeSql);
```